# DC compiler, synthesis, terminology

Tags: terminology, synthesis

In the DC compiler user manual the following term is reported when talking about a command.

> Use the set_driving_cell command to specify ***drive characteristics*** on
>   ports that are driven by cells in the technology library

Can anyone tell me what's the meaning of that "drive characteristic"?

Comment: Can you expand on what "DC compiler" means?

Comment: @Andrew Spott "Design Compiler compiler". A bit like "ATM machine" or "DC current", a symptom of [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome). It produces a [register-transfer level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register-transfer_level) integrated circuit design from a [hardware description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language) input.

Comment: @jms:  Thanks.  It is sometimes hard to know if you can answer a question if you don't know what the acronyms mean.

Comment: Design compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Drive characteristics of cells are mostly related to how much capacitance they can drive and how fast they can charge or discharge. Each cell in a technology library has look-up tables that show the relationship between the load (capacitance) and the timing (e.g. transition times).

If Design Compiler knows what cells are driving the input ports, it performs timing analysis more accurately and inserts buffers when needed.

In case the driving cells are unknown, it's better (for timing) to define weak cells on inputs to be on the safe side. Probably the circuit will consume more area and power, but DC will perform timing analysis for the worst case.

Strengths (driving capabilities) of the cells are generally comprehensible by the cell names. For example, `AND2X1` is a 2-input AND gate with X1 strength. `AND2X4` is a larger and stronger 2-input AND gate. Of course, all technology libraries have their own naming conventions, mine is just an arbitrary example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. It seems to me you're explaining what "driver characteristics" are used for, but I still don't have a definition for that. Do you have a definition for that?

Comment: @user8469759 I added the first paragraph and tried to explain.